# On Click div change input value

Tags: jquery, html

Basically what I'm trying to do is when you click 1 div it will set a hidden value to 1 and if you hit 2nd div sets hidden value to 2.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>  
            <?php
                //Fetch products from the database
                $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products");
                while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
                echo '
                    <div class="col-md-3 product" id="rankid'.$row['id'].'">
                        <h2>'.$row['name'].'</h2>
                        '.$row['pricename'].'<br><br>
                        '.$row['desc'].'<br><br>
                    </div>';
                }
            ?>
```

Heres my Javascript

```
document.getElementById("rankid1").onclick = function() {changeAmount1()};
document.getElementById("rankid2").onclick = function() {changeAmount2()};

function changeAmount1() {
    document.getElementById('amount').value = '5';
}
function changeAmount2() {
    document.getElementById('amount').value = '20';
}
```

[What It looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RughJ.png)

Comment: Tried to use a javascript on click change value but i don't think i did it right.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Just edited main post

Comment: What adjectly is the hidden value !! ,Nothing is clear !!

Comment: Edited again, i need to make the div a button that changes a hidden value for a form

Comment: getElementById is not looking for name.... Pretty easy to spot. Either add an id, or reference it by name.

Comment: changed to <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="5"> still doesnt change it

Comment: Well is there an error in your developer console?

Comment: nah doesnt say anything

Comment: So you need to debug and figure out why... does the click event get triggered?

Comment: nothing changes, im trying to make it so when you click the right div the id of amount changes to 20 and if you click the left it changes to 5 here is what it looks like http://img-u.com/gk

Comment: The code works with the change as you can see in my answer. So it is hard to debug why yours does not work. Make sure the PHP is generating the ids right and change it to be text instead of hidden so you can see the value change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5">  <-- has a name
document.getElementById('amount').value  <-- looking for an element with an id.
```

name does not equal id.

so either add `id="amount"` to the input

or reference it by name.

```
document.formName.amount.value
```

Also make sure you are adding your event handlers after the elements are rendered on the page.

```js
document.getElementById("rankid1").onclick = function() {
  changeAmount1()
};
document.getElementById("rankid2").onclick = function() {
  changeAmount2()
};

function changeAmount1() {
  document.getElementById('amount').value = '5';
}

function changeAmount2() {
  document.getElementById('amount').value = '20';
}
```

```css
.product {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="5">
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 product" id="rankid1">
    <h2>1</h2>
    1 abc<br><br>
    1 def<br><br>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 product" id="rankid2">
    <h2>2</h2>
    2 ghi<br><br>
    2 jkl<br><br>
  </div>
```

Comment: Tried to add id="amount" but no luck

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/styqrkz4/)

```
 $('div').on('click', function() {
   if ($(this).next('div').length === 1)
   // Set hidden field value 1
   else
   // Set hidden field value 2
 });
```